# PHP MYSQL Table delete button not working

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the query statement that I have. For some reason it works for another table I have but doesn't work with this table. I checked phpmyadmin to see if I would create an error but there were zero errors.

```
$Store_ID = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Store_ID',FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
//DELETE the Store

$query="DELETE FROM store_location WHERE Store_ID = :Store_ID";
$statement2=$db->prepare($query);
$statement2->bindValue(':Store_ID',$Store_ID);
$statement2->execute();
$statement2->closeCursor();
```

Here is the table code for the Delete Button

```
           <?php foreach ($stores as $s) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $s['Store_ID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['Loc_Street']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['Loc_City']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['Loc_State']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['Rent']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['License']; ?></td>   
            <td><?php echo $s['Inspect']; ?></td>  
            <td><form action="stores.php" method="post">
                    <input type ="hidden" name ="Store_ID" value ="<?php echo $s['Store_ID']; ?>"/>
                    <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"/>                
           </form></td>  
         </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: change the input type button, to submit

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 could just be this ! otherwise assuming it is submitting, (which it very well may not) what i often do when I have a query not working, is var_dump($query); and look at what its trying to do, even then taking that sql and put it into phpmyadmin sql section. in your case due to your framework you seem to be using you would need to get the final sql code after the ->bindValue has been run.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that changing it from "button" to "Submit" did the trick

Comment: @HaydenThring you may be right, but i am assuming his query is fine, but input type button will not submit the form, input type submit or button type submit will, in some browser

Comment: That's the whole difference between `type=submit` and `type=button`.

Comment: FYI you can also use the more modern `<button type="submit">Delete</button>`

Comment: I also just learnt the type argument is not even necessary